# cannot read configuration file - updated

Tags: iis

*I am having the same issue as I've seen elsewhere but can no longer comment or reply - must be too old a post.*

This happens only on my remote server running WIN2012, IIS 8.5 and on my brand new laptop, IIS 10.

I have been successful in running site on desktop **WIN7, IIS 7.5** system only. 
Seems it comes down to the computer's configuration. I needed to manually install IIS and other stuff on the WIN7 machine since none of it was there.

I don't believe the `web.config` file is the issue as you've stated, but something in the software installed is the problem.

Why can't this work cross platform? I am using the same folder paths. the "Test Settings" buttons may show errors, but sites other test sites still open (sites with an index file).

I have not found an answer and it's been weeks. If someone else can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Add some screen shots to reveal more details. Don't know what you are trying to do yet.

Comment: Will get what I can, but not sure what will reveal the most info to you. I have a site built in VS 2015, all production code runs locally on WIN7, IIS 7.5 (which I installed). Code does not run on remote server WIN2012 Server, IIS 8.5 or on my new laptop WIN10 IIS 10 - always shows some sort of error. The error is not what concerns me as much as why the code will not run cross platform. Sounds like setting up IIS is simple enough, but it's completely different apparenty.

Comment: Then is it against your intuition to paste at least the entire error page like so many others did?

Comment: I will log in here with the laptop so I can run it there and get a shot.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to log in from the laptop and am unable to change my password here, so no screen shot is possibly unless I use my iphone. What did you need to see?

Comment: well there you go - cannot put a screen shot here.

Comment: under 'Test Settings': 'cannot verify access to path' - this error is a false positive as I have regular index.html sites running which also show this error. Need to think way out of the box on this issue. The guy I bought the site from is a .NET expert who worked for Google and kept insisting my connection string was incorrect when it was. This is an IIS issue caused by how it is configured out of the box on different platforms.